# Beautifulsoup filter "find_all" results, limited to .jpeg file via Regex

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, jpeg, gif

I would like to acquire some pictures from a forum. The find_all results gives me most what I want, which are jpeg files. However It also gives me few gif files which I do not desire. Another problem is that the gif file is an attachment, not a valid link, and it causes trouble when I save files.

```
soup_imgs = soup.find(name='div', attrs={'class':'t_msgfont'}).find_all('img', alt="")
for i in soup_imgs:
    src = i['src']
    print(src)
```

I tried to avoid that gif files in my find_all selections search, but useless, both jpeg and gif files are in the same section. What should I do to filter my result then? Please give me some help, chief. I am pretty amateur with coding. Playing with Python is just a hobby of mine.

Comment: could you provide sample output and additional code (provide a dummy site url if desired)?  also, not knowing the details, have you tried simple ` if ` condition to filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter it via regular expression.Please refer the following example.Hope this helps.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<html>
<body>

<h2>List of images</h2>

<div class="t_msgfont">
<img src="img_chania.jpeg" alt="" width="460" height="345">
<img src="wrongname.gif" alt="">
<img src="img_girl.jpeg" alt="" width="500" height="600">
</div>
</body>
</html>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
soup_imgs = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'t_msgfont'}).find_all('img', alt="" ,src=re.compile(".jpeg"))
for i in soup_imgs:
    src = i['src']
    print(src)
```

Comment: src=re.compile(".jpeg") nailed it, powerful! thanks mate

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

Try the following which I suspect you can shorten. It uses the ends with operator ($) to specify that the src attributes value of the child img elements ends with .jpg  (edited to jpg from jpeg in light of OP's comment that it is actually jpg)

```
srcs = [item['src'] for item in soup.select("div.t_msgfont img[alt=''][src$='.jpg']")]
```

Have a look at shortening the selector(I can't without seeing the HTML in question), you may well get away with something like

```
srcs = [item['src'] for item in soup.select(".t_msgfont [alt=''][src$='.jpg']")]
```

or even

```
srcs = [item['src'] for item in soup.select(".t_msgfont [src$='.jpg']")]
```

Comment: do i need to import anything to use "$"? It seems my script keeps giving me invalid syntax.

Comment: Try now. I hadn't changed the inner "" to ''

Comment: weird, it's running, but no result from [src$='.jpeg'], I checked the file extension, they are jpg, when I get rid of the "e", syntax error...

Comment: So you get that error with srcs = [item['src'] for item in soup.select("div.t_msgfont img[alt=''][src$='.jpg']")]

Comment: Try the above and also try srcs = [item['src'] for item in soup.select(".t_msgfont [src$='jpg']")]

Comment: No worries though I am a little confused as to how the other solution worked if the extension is actually jpg?

Comment: I am not sure either, import re, re.compile worked somehow, I gotta look it up in the books. I haven't reach re section yet.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [requests-html](https://html.python-requests.org/) to find the image resources in the page.
It's pretty simple compared to `BeautifulSoup` + `requests`.

Here's the code to do it.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
resp = session.get(url)
for i in resp.html.absolute_links:
    if i.endswith('.jpeg'):
        print(i)
```

Comment: thanks chief, I will look into it. I have a lot to revise for my codes as amateurs.